# How to calculate seasonal component from weekly data using dataframepython?

Tags: python, data-analysis, climate-data

Below is my dataframe

[image: This is my dataframe]

I want to calculate the climatological monthly average, the total average for each month.

For example, when I use groupby to estimate the monthly average of the variable AREA as below

annual_average = df.groupby(by=[pd.Grouper(key='TIME', freq='M')])['AREA'].mean().reset_index()

it gives me this below (weekly average for each month for each year):

[image: Weekly average for each month]

I want to calculate the average for each month but over the years from 1981 to 2018

Many thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49812107/3038828 looks worthwhile?  Wouldn't even use Grouper it doesn't look like